# Cakephp 2.x where clause on multi level

Tags: cakephp

Here's my models

MODEL USERLIST

```
class UserList extends AppModel {

public $belongsTo = array(
    'UserOwner' => array(
        'className' => 'Usermgmt.User',
        'foreignKey' => 'owner_id'
    ),
    'UserMember' => array(
        'className' => 'Usermgmt.User',
        'foreignKey' => 'member_id'
    )
);
public $recursive = -1;
public $actsAs = array('Containable');
```

MODEL USER

```
class User extends UserMgmtAppModel {

public $actsAs = array('Containable');

/**
 * This model belongs to following models
 *
 * @var array
 */
var $belongsTo = array('Usermgmt.UserGroup');

/**
 * This model has following models
 *
 * @var array
 */
var $hasMany = array(
    'LoginToken' => array('className' => 'Usermgmt.LoginToken', 'limit' => 1),
    'UserListOwner' => array('className' => 'UserList', 'foreignKey' => 'owner_id'),
    'UserListMember' => array('className' => 'UserList', 'foreignKey' => 'member_id'),
);
var $hasOne = array(
    'PhoneNumber' => array('className' => 'PhoneNumber', 'foreignKey' => 'user_id')
);
```

MODEL PHONENUMBER

```
class PhoneNumber extends AppModel {

public $belongsTo = array(
    'User' => array(
        'className' => 'Usermgmt.User'
    )
);
```

I want to do a database request on multiple parameters who are on multiple levels. This is my request.

```
  $this->UserList->find("all", array('conditions' => array(
        "UserList.type" => 1,
        'UserList.owner_id' => $this->UserAuth->getUserId(),
        "UserMember.PhoneNumber.phoneNumber LIKE" => "%" . "514" . "%"
    ), 'fields'=>array('UserMember.first_name', 'UserMember.last_name', "PhoneNumber.phoneNumber")))
```

My problem is when I run this request, I always receive an SQL error message who says that the field UserMember.PhoneNumber.phoneNumber does not exists.

I can do that request using standard SQL but i'dd like to do it with CakePhp.

How can I do it?

thanks

Comment: can you post the standard SQL you'd like to create with cake?

Comment: You mayuse either containable feature or join query.

Comment: this is the sql I liked to have         ` select u.first_name, u.last_name,p.phoneNumber from user_lists as ul left join users as u on u.id=ul.member_id left join phone_numbers as p on p.user_id=u.id where ul.type='1' AND ul.owner_id='56fc0b23-ad1c-474b-bc70-4e5e4837' AND p.phoneNumber like '%514%' `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your column name is wrong, this line `"UserMember.PhoneNumber.phoneNumber LIKE" => "%" . "514" . "%"` should be `"PhoneNumber.phoneNumber LIKE" => "%" . "514" . "%"` from the looks of things like you have in your `fields`.

You might also need to specify which models you want to contain like this:-

```
$this->UserList->find(
    'all', 
    array(
        'contain' => array(
            'UserMember' => array('PhoneNumber')
        ),
        'conditions' => array(
            'UserList.type' => 1,
            'UserList.owner_id' => $this->UserAuth->getUserId(),
            'PhoneNumber.phoneNumber LIKE' => '%' . '514' . '%'
        ), 
        'fields'=>array(
            'UserMember.first_name', 
            'UserMember.last_name', 
            'PhoneNumber.phoneNumber'
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: Hi drmonkeyninja, here is the sql query produce by your code

SELECT `UserMember`.`first_name`, `UserMember`.`last_name`, `PhoneNumber`.`phoneNumber`, `UserMember`.`id` FROM `Get2uDev`.`user_lists` AS `UserList` LEFT JOIN `Get2uDev`.`users` AS `UserMember` ON (`UserList`.`member_id` = `UserMember`.`id`) WHERE `UserList`.`type` = 1 AND `UserList`.`owner_id` = '56fc0b23-ad1c-474b-bc70-4e5e4837' AND `PhoneNumber`.`phoneNumber` LIKE '%514%'

I still get the following sql error  Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'PhoneNumber.phoneNumber' in 'field list'